# Trouble derivating an equation with matrices and vectors.

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

I have the following equation $p=(1+r)(pA+wl)$ where ***w***, ***r*** are scalars; ***p***, ***l*** are vectors; ***A*** is a matrix. I want to prove that an increase in ***w*** would lead to a decrease in ***A*** or ***l*** (i.e., ***p*** is constant). For that purpose I first try to refolmulate as
$$A=\frac{p-wl(1+r)}{p(1+r)}$$     $$l=\frac{p(1-A(1+r))}{w(1+r)}$$

Then I thought of derivating both equations with respect to ***w***, but I feel lost. For example, in the first equation it is impossible to divide two column vectors. Is there any other way to prove that an increase in ***w*** would lead to a decrease of ***A*** or **l**.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean that $p$ stays constant?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I forgot to say that. Sorry.

Comment: Well, it's a little unclear to me what a decrease in a matrix or vector would mean. Anyway, we can argue that
$$
\frac{p}{1+r} = pA + wl
$$
statys constant. In the beginning we have $pA_0 + w_0 l_0$ and in the end same with index $1$. Then
$$
pA_0 + w_0 l_0 = pA_1 + w_1 l_1
$$
etc ...

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. So there is no way to derivate?

Comment: You should say that $p$ and $l$ are **row**-vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I insist : expression $A=\frac{p-wl(1+r)}{p(1+r)}$ cannot be used because you cannot divide by a **row** vector, not a **column** vector.

Comment: MattiP. is correct, you need to explain what you mean by "a decrease in ***A*** or ***l***". Matrices and vectors are not ordered like numbers are. (You can give them a "partial ordering", but I suspect this isn't what you mean.) What are you actually trying to accomplish that you think you need this? It is likely that the real issue occurred before you got this far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the differential of the relationship
$$\eqalign{
p &= (1+r)(pA+wl) \\
}$$
to obtain (assuming $p,r$ are constant)
$$\eqalign{
0 &= (1+r)(p\,dA + l\,dw+ w\,dl) \\
l\,dw &= -(p\,dA + w\,dl) \\
}$$

This indicates how $(A,l)$ would need to change to compensate for a change in $w$, in such a way that $p$ is held constant.

For example, if you want to vary only $l$, then change its length (but not its *direction*) by the amount
$$dl = -\frac{l\;dw}{w} = -l\;d\log(w)$$
Or hold $l$ constant and change the magnitude/direction of $A$ by the amount $dA$, such that 
$$p\;dA = -l\;dw$$
is satisfied.